# CSS transitions backface visibility in Android Webkit

Tags: android, css

I am developing a mobile web based page that uses CSS transitions and 3D transformations. I have ran into a bug with Android 3.1 Webkit and I can't seem to find a solution to it.

I use CSS rotations so that I basically have an element with the parameter `backface-visibility: hidden;` and then I add a class to this element to start the transformation.

```
#flipper {
    -webkit-transform-origin: center center;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.rotating-cover-effect {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

**The problem is that on Android (specifically 3.1) the backface of the `#flipper` is still visible after the rotation.** On iOS or with desktop Webkit browsers (i.e Chrome, Safari) the background is hidden correctly.

Is this a bug in Android Webkit or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: not that it helps, but -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden; is causing all kind of havoc on my Android (2.3) if the element it's assigned to contains any form elements.

Answer (score 0):

Are you making an Android app? If so, you need to enable hardware acceleration by adding this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" ...>
```

If you're making an actual website, http://thewebrocks.com/demos/3D-css-tester/ can help you conclude whether it's a problem with what you're doing or with the browser implementation.